# Laravel+PHPunit, testing <select> with default option

Tags: php, html, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm writing a test for a view and I'm using native phpunit + laravel test suite without any third parties packages because I think that they suit my needs.

I've only one question tho, which is basically written in the title, how do I test a `<select>` tag with an `<option disabled selected="true"/>`?

This is the HTML inside the blade.

```
<select name="from[hour]" id="fromHour" class="form-control">
    <option disabled aria-disabled="true" selected aria-selected="true">Hour</option>
    @for($i = 1; $i <= 24; ++$i)
        <option value="{{ $i }}" {{ (old("from.hour") == $i) ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $i }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

Don't look at the styling, it's just a dummy select. Now my test suite is using the classic `fillForm` + `select($value, $name)` method combo to fill the entire form the problem is that if I leave the `<option selected/>` element, the test will fail because it will stick with the default option **but** if I remove that `<option selected />` the test will chose a random number from the `<select>` element which is fine and intended.

Here's the code involved

```
$dumpResult = $this->visit("foo/bar")
             ->seeText("Save Form")
             ->select($randomNumber, "from[hour]")
             ->fillForm("Save Form", [
                 "name" => Factory::create()->firstName,
                 "surname" => Factory::create()->lastName,
             ]);
```

If I `dd` the result of `dumpResult` it will shows me any random number within the range, which is intended,  because there isn't any default option but that is not the case when there is a default option.

I need that default option, and I cannot change the whole application only because the test suite is unable to fetch the `<select>` element. What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried giving your default option a value that would evaluate as falsy?

Comment: @DavidBarker I'm not following you, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: `<option disabled selected value="-1">Hour</option>`

Comment: Nope, is not working. The test will always take the value inside the `InnerHTML` :(